# How can I map buttons on my PS3 controller to keystrokes on my Mac?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, input-source

I purchased a PlayStation 3 controller for use with my Mac. It's paired via Bluetooth. It works great in emulators such as Snes9x, but I'd like to use it for other things as well. Is there any software that will allow me to map buttons on the controller to keystrokes?

I've tried USB Overdrive and as far as I can tell, it doesn't do what I want.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there's an application called "ControllerMate" that you can get here http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/ . You pair the controller to the mac with USB (I think Bluetooth will work too but you might have to look up special instructions), then use this app to bind the controller functions to keys and mouse movements. It works really well. I used to use it to play things like Portal because they don't natively support the PS3 controller.

Comment: ControllerMate is by far the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

### [Enjoy](https://github.com/fyhuang/enjoy2) allows to map buttons to keystrokes.

Here is the mapping I determined for my PS3 controller (connected via Bluetooth):
The `OSX` mapping is used in games that directly support controllers, as [Dustforce](http://dustforce.com/) - where the `SELECT` button is mapped as `pad0_btn3`; there you would, of course, not use [Enjoy](https://github.com/fyhuang/enjoy2).

> Enjoy is a free program for Mac OS X 10.5+, focused on simplicity.

```
+------------------+---------------+-------------+
|      button      | Enjoy mapping | OSX mapping |
+------------------+---------------+-------------+
| left             |             8 |           7 |
| up               |             5 |           4 |
| right            |             6 |           5 |
| down             |             7 |           6 |
| L1               |            11 |          10 |
| L2               |             9 |           8 |
| R1               |            12 |          11 |
| R2               |            10 |           9 |
| select           |             1 |           0 |
| start            |             4 |           3 |
| PS-btn           |            17 |          16 |
| L3(left analog)  |             2 |           1 |
| R3(right analog) |             3 |           2 |
| ◻ square         |            16 |          15 |
| △ triangle       |            13 |          12 |
| ◯ circle         |            14 |          13 |
| X cross          |            15 |          14 |
+------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the procedure described here http://forums.macnn.com/77/gaming/377671/gaming-on-mac-with-ps3-controller/

Answer (score 0):

The PS3 remote works with [Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) if you're prepared to pay 20 euros (obviously test it out first though — it has a free trial period)